# Undefined variable: eavSetup magento 2

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

I checkout from version SVn and i tried to run setup upgrade but it show me this error [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your "Undefine variable: eavSetup" error, you are facing issue in your Mdweb_MonetiquePaiement module.

First Disable that module and run below command:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

Hope it help!

Let me know if any issue comes.

Comment: Welcome happy to help!

Comment: can you please help me in this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249768/sudo-php-bin-magento-setupupgrade-no-such-entity-magento-2

Comment: Sure check my comment at your question.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command with -vvv, you will increase the verbosity of messages.

```
bin/magento -vvv setup:upgrade
```

Comment: same error  ??!!

Comment: But more verbose for sure, can you please edit your question and add it?