# sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade No such entity magento 2

Tags: magento2

I get this error when running the setup:upgrade. I have changed the secure url to the new url but nothing changed please any help

Comment: Remove  var directory except .htaccess file and run command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Let me know any further issue.

Comment: i got the same erreor

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your http directory and run following:

```
rm -R var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

Then try to run `setup:upgrade` again.

Comment: i got the same erreor

Answer (score 0):

Remove content from folder /generated on the root of the Magento 2 project, plus /var content except for the logs and run again the setup:upgrade. Compile afterward with setup:di:compile to ensure that everything is on track and generated.